# style a search box and search button using CSS

Tags: css, xhtml

I am having problems with my search box, the search box has a gap between the search button and this problem only exists in IE7/8/9. But its fine in Firefox.

**EDIT:** In IE the cursor is also higher but perfect in Firefox.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/bM7PQ/

**HTML:**

```
<form action="search.aspx" method="get" class="topsearchform" name="topsearchform">
    <fieldset>

    <!--<label>Search:</label>-->

    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="Text1" class="searchBox" name="SearchTerm" size="15">
    <input width="23" type="image" height="23" border="0" onclick="document.topsearchform.submit()" alt="Submit Form" src="http://i45.tinypic.com/ojkznb.png" class="searchButton">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
form.topsearchform {
    left: 70px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 87px;
    width: 139px;
}

#topLinks form fieldset {
    vertical-align: middle;
}


#Text1 {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("http://i46.tinypic.com/35c0n78.png");
    border: 0 none;
    height: 23px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    width: 130px;
}


input.searchButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("http://i49.tinypic.com/r0rrtl.png");
    position: absolute;
}
```

**Issue in IE:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to `input.searchButton`

```
left:133px;
```

Comment: Sorry this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

have you applied a css reset of any type before your own styles? this helps a lot as it tends to normalize the way html elements are displayed on different browsers.

Comment: added a css reset and did the fix that @Somebody is in trouble suggested but problem still occurs. http://jsfiddle.net/bM7PQ/3/

Answer (score 1):

this does what you need and without position: absolute, check the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LvP43/

```
form.topsearchform {
    left: 70px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 87px;
    width: 159px;
}

#topLinks form fieldset {
    vertical-align: middle;
}


#Text1 {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("http://i46.tinypic.com/35c0n78.png");
    border: 0 none;
    height: 23px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    width: 130px;
    float: left;
}


input.searchButton {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: url("http://i49.tinypic.com/r0rrtl.png");
    float: left;
}
```